# How does R deal with binary numbers with mantissa more than 53 digits?

Tags: r, binary

I have a question about numbers with more than 53 digits in mantissa. Say `10^16+3`, its binary expansion is `100011100001101111001001101111110000010000000000000011` which has 54 digits in its mantissa.

I was thinking the last digit will be ignored. According to this assumption, the decimal number of the binary string after ignoring the last digit should be `10^16+2`, but R returns `10^16+4`.

The same situations happens for `10^16+7`, where it should be `10^16+6`, but returns `10^16+8`. Anybody knows why?

Comment: Since R uses binary64 scheme, it can store a binary number with less than or equal to 53digits. But what if a number's binary expansion has more than 53 digits? How would R deal with the digits after the 53rd digit? Because the example I gave, 10^16+3, its binary expansion has 54 digits, with the last two digits being 1. Since R can only store the first 53 digits, what will happen to the 1 in the 54th digit? If R does ignore the last 1, wouldn't it return the decimal value of 10^16+3 to be 10^16+2 rather than 10^16+4? Hope this clarifies the confusion.

Comment: The source code;  it's available. It's just going to be what the C compiler does on your platform. It's not guaranteed to be any particular action and might vary from OS to OS.